# Im outsourced, do I still get paid if quarantine pops up?

Tags: software-industry, work-environment

I am currently working for a company that outsources me, if we get in quarantine will I get fired and stop being paid in case they freeze operations?

Comment: What does your contract say?

Comment: I guess I dont have a copy ;(

Comment: @IceeFrog, you should try and get a copy. What does your manager say?

Comment: He said we probly hit home office but company gotta stop operations because of the low demand, i got qn answer of the outsource saying “lets wait until it happens to see how it goes” ._.

Comment: This is entirely based on your contract and applicable local laws. Without this information, I don't think we can possibly answer it. Perhaps you could edit your question with a country tag (and, if necessary, region tag), and also find out what your contract says and then edit it into your question.

Comment: Most likely not: The whole idea of outsourcing is to get rid of such costs as sick pay.

Comment: Maybe not. Outsourced people often have regular work contracts, just in another country etc. - but the local employment laws still apply, they are not taken out just because.

Answer (score 3):

If you get paid it will depend specifically on several things:

- The contract between your employer and the customer. It may specify if the work can be done from home, or from another site. This will determine if your employer can get money from their customer if you aren't in your normal work location.
- The contract between your employer and you. This will cover such topics as sick leave, and short term disability if you do get sick. This will also discuss paid time off.
- National and local laws that cover sick leave rules, or other related labor issues.

In addition your employer may have other projects/contracts you can work on that will have a more flexible work location requirement.

You should ask your employer for clarification about your situation. The exact answer will depend on your exact situation. Not only can it differ between contracts, but it can also differ within a contract.